# Appending text to gzipped logfile

Tags: bash, shell, tee

is there a way to "simply" append logging text to a gzipped logfile ?

A kind of `echo "foo" | tee -a /tmp/foo.log.gz`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply concatenate gzipped content, but it will not be as small as gzipping concatenated text, due to header that each block will have.

```
# fast and somewhat inefficient
echo foo | gzip >> foo.log.gz

# small but slow
gunzip foo.log.gz && echo foo > foo.log && gzip foo.log
```

Comment: Is this something that just happens to work with GNU `gzip`, or is it a feature of the `gzip` file format (and can thus be relied on to always work)?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Feature of `gzip` format, and of how `gunzip` works. `gzip` is a series of independent blocks, each with a header (optionally with various metadata, e.g. file name in case the input was a file). However, `gunzip` will transparently concatenate all the blocks (ignoring the file names where they exist).

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no, if you also want to `tee`.  You could do

```
echo "foo" | tee fifo | gzip -c >>/tmp/foo.log.gz
```

and then separately run `tail -f fifo`.  (It could be a file, or a FIFO socket, as the name suggests.)